# Javascript Do I need a closure in my nested for loop or not?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I make sure my data goes in the correct place?

I am using KnockoutJS foreach but only one foreach and not nested ones in the HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: locationsFilteredYears">
        <tr>  
             <td data-bind="text: Month"></td>
         </tr>    
         <tr>  
             <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
         </tr>    
</tbody>
```

Controller:

```
var j: any;
      for(i=0;i<filteredEvents.length;i++){
        for(j=0+i;j<months.length;j++){
          if(months[j].value,filteredEvents[i].StartDate.substring(3, 5)){
            filteredEvents[i].Month = months[j].name;
            console.log(months[j].name);
            console.log(months[i].name);
          }
        }
      }

//push to view
this.locationsFilteredYears(filteredEvents);
```

Result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON6V5.png)

Expected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JImMR.png)

Comment: `if(months[j].value,filteredEvents[i]` maybe `==` not `,`

Comment: Thanks I think this was more of an issue with UI and me still not learned the ropes fully yet with KnockoutJS. My frontend was messy and I am still confused as to how to properly filter the backend functions or observables and then the proper syntax for each one on the frontend to output a nested for loop. I know there's a few different ways of doing it but I feel there's quite a few characters at weird positions in frontend that confused me too much having come from more standard MVC stacks (Angular, C#, ASP etc) and having spent last 14 months with ReactJS. That said I posted my answer...

Answer (score 0):

After being lost in the frontend and as mentioned my comment still not fully grasped Observables and MVVM way of things...I ended up not using not using Knockout bindings and my working version now looks like so:

```
//Manually Create months
var mTblRowJan = '';
    var mTblRowFeb = '';
    var mTblRowMar = '';
    var mTblRowApr = '';
    ...

//Filter through array of api data
filteredEvents.forEach((a) => {

//pull out data month by month
//I.e. for jan it's
     if(a["Start_x0020_Date"].indexOf('-01-') > -1){
          mTblRowJan += `<tr><td>`+a.Title+`</td><td>`+this.formatDate(a["Start_x0020_Date"].toString())+`</td><td>`+this.formatDate(a["End_x0020_Date"].toString())+`</td><td><a href='https://web.powerapps.com/apps/?event_id='`+a.Id+`'>Book</a></td></tr>`;
                  console.log(a["Start_x0020_Date"].toString(), a.Title);
        }
});

//Build table manually in backend with manually created Months labels for seperation
//and add dynamic row
//this can contain as many tables rows as needed for any given month
 var mTbl = `<table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
              <th scope="col">End Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Booking</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                  <tr><td><h4>JANUARY</h4> </td></tr>  
                  ` +mTblRowJan+ `      
          </tbody>
        </table>`;

//push table to view
this.tblTest(mTbl);


//As you can see not using Knockout and it's a just a dynamic JS table so any advice on how to turn this version to use nested data-binds in front end would be helpful!
```